# Description for Electorate badge

Tags: discussion, badges, electorate-badge

The current description for [Electorate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/155/electorate) badge is:

```
Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions
```

This sounds a bit strange. Voted on `X` were at least 25% is `X`.
Should the word "Post" be used instead? Or word "answer" to be more clear.

First suggestion:

```
Voted on 600 posts and 25% or more of total votes are on questions
```

**Edit:** Second suggestion: [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) description (which strange enough is not the same as the badge page):

```
Vote on 600 questions, and have at least 25% of the total number of votes cast be votes on questions
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your proposal changes the meaning.

You actually need to vote on 600 *questions* for that badge. And, in addition to that, those 600 question votes must represent at least 25% of your total votes (votes on questions plus votes on answers).

The description is accurate.

Say you voted on 600 posts in total, with 150 votes on questions, 450 on answers. That satisfies the percentage criteria. It doesn't satisfy the number of question votes criteria. So you don't get the badge.

If you voted on 600 questions and nothing else, you get the badge (100% of total votes on questions).

If you voted on 600 questions and 5400 answers, you meet the question vote criteria, but not the percentage criteria (you're only at 10% of votes on questions).

Comment: Well is a question not a post? Otherwise the word answer should be mentioned also.

Comment: It is. But an answer is also a post. If you voted on 600 questions, and 6000 posts in total (so 600 Q, 5400 A), you don't get the badge. If you voted on 600 posts 25% of them being questions (150 Q and 450 A), you don't get the badge.

Comment: Ok, that is true, but needed a better explanation that you gave now. The description is not clear. Maybe the description with the word "Answer" somewhere should be better than as is now, in my opinion.

Comment: "and 25% or more of the votes on questions and answers are votes on questions"? That's even more confusing to me.

Comment: What about "Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total Votes Cast are on questions". That would be more clear maybe.

Comment: @Rikard: Total votes versus total votes cast? What else can you do with votes except cast them?

Comment: Well, i used the Word used in the profile, were the number of the Vote Cast actually is. Otherwise I don't see anywere in my profile the number for "total votes".

Comment: Interesting that you voted duplicate to my question, in the original the words "votes cast" is used. Can we not use it?

Comment: @Sergio: I have nothing against using "votes cast" there, I just completely fail to see how that makes the sentence clearer. Counting votes you haven't cast isn't really an option. As for the dup: as I added in the comment there, I didn't remember there was a nice explanation with a table. I wouldn't have written an answer if I had.

Comment: Well, I rest my case. Seems that it's just me thinking like this. I don't agree but you are up-voted by community, I get downvoted so answer accepted to you.

Comment: @Sergio: don't be in a rush accepting. Someone did vote this answer down, so there might be other answers coming up with a different take.

Comment: @Mat, it was me downvoting, because I don't agree. So I'm alone in this one :)

Comment: @Sergio: ah, ok :-) I still think you shouldn't accept if you're expecting an answer with a different wording that would work better (and would still be short enough in whatever space there is to display it).

Comment: Well, 2 downvoted and 2 close votes. I leave it. Btw, the description on link you posted "Vote on 600 questions, and have at least 25% of the total number of votes cast be votes on questions", should be the one to be in the badge. Many badges have a 2 row description. I go to bed, Swedish people go to be early :) Salut!